# Angular1 ng-show doesn't show the span even though the condition is true

Tags: angularjs

I have an accordion list as following:

```
<ion-list>
  <div ng-repeat="day in days"><br>
    <div class="item item-icon-left"  ng-click="toggleGroup(day)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
      <i class="icon icon-accessory" ng-class="isGroupShown(day) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp;
      {{day.name}}
    </div>
    <a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(day)" ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises" type="item-text-wrap"
       href="#/tab/plan/{{exercise.id}}">
      {{exercise.name}}

      <!-- Trial LED -->

        <span ng-show="{{exercise.watchedToday}}==true" style="float:right;"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>

    </a>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

On initial component load even though the condition is true i.e. `{{exercise.watchedToday}}==true` the span is not shown. If I put {{exercise.watchedToday}} above span it prints true but the span is not shown.

When I click on the link > some other component loads > and if I come back It is visible.

Why does it happen? It it because of multiple conditions i.e. ng-repeat, ng-show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the curly brackets in `ng-show`. since `ng-show` is an angular directive no need to use curly brackets

```
 <span ng-show="exercise.watchedToday" style="float:right;"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>
```